# Libgdx - gdx.video blank screen

Tags: java, libgdx, video-player

I'm kinda new to LibGDX and I'm just trying to play a video using the [gdx-video](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-video) library, running the desktop project on my linux machine results a blank screen with no errors.

Code:

```
videoPlayer = VideoPlayerCreator.createVideoPlayer();
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_CULL_FACE);
Gdx.gl.glCullFace(GL20.GL_BACK);

try {
    FileHandle videoFile = game.manager.getIntroVideo();
    Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Loading file : " + videoFile.file().getAbsolutePath());
    videoPlayer.play(videoFile);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Err: " + e);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.3f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
}
```

I've tried almost all formats (mkv,ogv,webm,mp4) with the same effect, Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your render method insert: videoPlayer.render();

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
   ...
   videoPlayer.render();
}
```